# What have I done incorrectly in compiling or installing GCAL library?

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, cgal

I'm not an experienced C/C++ programmer. Recently, in my workflow, I need to use CGAL. 
I'm currently using Ubuntu, installed the library through apt get, so I assume that all dependencies have met.

Anyways, I tried to compile an example by myself. Copy the .cpp file to a separate folder.

First command to generate CMake file:

```
/usr/bin/cgal_create_CMakeLists -s skeleton_generation
```

This gave me a CMakeLists. I then use cmake to compile:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release .
```

Everything is still going well, until I tried the "make" command, this error pop up:

```
Scanning dependencies of target skeleton_generation
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/skeleton_generation.dir/skeleton_generation.cpp.o
/home/anh/Desktop/Project/CGAL-5.0/my_example/skeleton/skeleton_generation.cpp:5:10: fatal error: print.h: No such file or directory
 #include "print.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/skeleton_generation.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/skeleton_generation.dir/skeleton_generation.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/skeleton_generation.dir/skeleton_generation.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/skeleton_generation.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/skeleton_generation.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Ok, weird. Well, I guess I'm just not gonna use the special print function then. Comment out the print function, I still got more errors. All of them are undefined references to some function...:

```
Scanning dependencies of target skeleton_generation
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/skeleton_generation.dir/skeleton_generation.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable skeleton_generation
CMakeFiles/skeleton_generation.dir/skeleton_generation.cpp.o: In function `boost::thread_specific_ptr<CORE::MemoryPool<CORE::Realbase_for<long>, 1024> >::~thread_specific_ptr()':
/usr/include/boost/thread/tss.hpp:79: undefined reference to `boost::detail::set_tss_data(void const*, boost::shared_ptr<boost::detail::tss_cleanup_function>, void*, bool)'
CMakeFiles/skeleton_generation.dir/skeleton_generation.cpp.o: In function `boost::thread_specific_ptr<CORE::MemoryPool<CORE::AddSubRep<CORE::Add>, 1024> >::~thread_specific_ptr()':
/usr/include/boost/thread/tss.hpp:79: undefined reference to `boost::detail::set_tss_data(void const*, boost::shared_ptr<boost::detail::tss_cleanup_function>, void*, bool)'
CMakeFiles/skeleton_generation.dir/skeleton_generation.cpp.o: In function `boost::thread_specific_ptr<CORE::MemoryPool<CORE::AddSubRep<CORE::Sub>, 1024> >::~thread_specific_ptr()':
/usr/include/boost/thread/tss.hpp:79: undefined reference to `boost::detail::set_tss_data(void const*, boost::shared_ptr<boost::detail::tss_cleanup_function>, void*, bool)'
CMakeFiles/skeleton_generation.dir/skeleton_generation.cpp.o: In function `boost::thread_specific_ptr<CORE::MemoryPool<CORE::Realbase_for<CORE::BigRat>, 1024> >::~thread_specific_ptr()':
/usr/include/boost/thread/tss.hpp:79: undefined reference to `boost::detail::set_tss_data(void const*, boost::shared_ptr<boost::detail::tss_cleanup_function>, void*, bool)'
CMakeFiles/skeleton_generation.dir/skeleton_generation.cpp.o: In function `boost::thread_specific_ptr<CORE::MemoryPool<CORE::ConstPolyRep<CORE::Expr>, 1024> >::~thread_specific_ptr()':
/usr/include/boost/thread/tss.hpp:79: undefined reference to `boost::detail::set_tss_data(void const*, boost::shared_ptr<boost::detail::tss_cleanup_function>, void*, bool)'
CMakeFiles/skeleton_generation.dir/skeleton_generation.cpp.o:/usr/include/boost/thread/tss.hpp:79: more undefined references to `boost::detail::set_tss_data(void const*, boost::shared_ptr<boost::detail::tss_cleanup_function>, void*, bool)' follow
CMakeFiles/skeleton_generation.dir/skeleton_generation.cpp.o: In function `CORE::RCRepImpl<CORE::BigFloatRep>::decRef()':
/usr/include/CGAL/CORE/RefCount.h:74: undefined reference to `CORE::BigIntRep::operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
/usr/include/CGAL/CORE/RefCount.h:74: undefined reference to `CORE::BigFloatRep::operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
CMakeFiles/skeleton_generation.dir/skeleton_generation.cpp.o: In function `boost::optional<CGAL::Line_2<CGAL::Epeck> > CGAL::CGAL_SS_i::compute_normalized_line_ceoffC2<CGAL::Epeck>(CGAL::Segment_2<CGAL::Epeck> const&)':
/usr/include/CGAL/CORE/BigFloat.h:64: undefined reference to `CORE::BigFloatRep::operator new(unsigned long)'
/usr/include/CGAL/CORE/BigFloat.h:64: undefined reference to `CORE::BigFloatRep::BigFloatRep(double)'
/usr/include/CGAL/CORE/BigFloat.h:54: undefined reference to `CORE::BigFloatRep::operator new(unsigned long)'
CMakeFiles/skeleton_generation.dir/skeleton_generation.cpp.o: In function `boost::optional<CGAL::Line_2<CGAL::Epeck> > CGAL::CGAL_SS_i::compute_normalized_line_ceoffC2<CGAL::Epeck>(CGAL::Segment_2<CGAL::Epeck> const&)':
/usr/include/CGAL/CORE/BigInt.h:126: undefined reference to `CORE::BigIntRep::operator new(unsigned long)'
CMakeFiles/skeleton_generation.dir/skeleton_generation.cpp.o: In function `boost::optional<CGAL::Line_2<CGAL::Epeck> > CGAL::CGAL_SS_i::compute_normalized_line_ceoffC2<CGAL::Epeck>(CGAL::Segment_2<CGAL::Epeck> const&)':
/usr/include/CGAL/CORE/BigFloat.h:354: undefined reference to `CORE::defBFsqrtAbsPrec'
/usr/include/CGAL/CORE/BigFloat.h:354: undefined reference to `CORE::BigFloatRep::sqrt(CORE::BigFloatRep const&, CORE::extLong const&)'
/usr/include/CGAL/CORE/BigFloat.h:221: undefined reference to `CORE::BigFloatRep::toDouble() const'
CMakeFiles/skeleton_generation.dir/skeleton_generation.cpp.o: In function `boost::optional<CGAL::Line_2<CGAL::Epeck> > CGAL::CGAL_SS_i::compute_normalized_line_ceoffC2<CGAL::Epeck>(CGAL::Segment_2<CGAL::Epeck> const&)':
/usr/include/CGAL/CORE/RefCount.h:74: undefined reference to `CORE::BigIntRep::operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
/usr/include/CGAL/CORE/RefCount.h:74: undefined reference to `CORE::BigFloatRep::operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
/usr/include/CGAL/CORE/RefCount.h:74: undefined reference to `CORE::BigIntRep::operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
/usr/include/CGAL/CORE/RefCount.h:74: undefined reference to `CORE::BigFloatRep::operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
CMakeFiles/skeleton_generation.dir/skeleton_generation.cpp.o: In function `boost::optional<CGAL::Line_2<CGAL::Epeck> > CGAL::CGAL_SS_i::compute_normalized_line_ceoffC2<CGAL::Epeck>(CGAL::Segment_2<CGAL::Epeck> const&)':
/usr/include/CGAL/CORE/BigFloat.h:64: undefined reference to `CORE::BigFloatRep::operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
/usr/include/CGAL/CORE/BigFloat.h:54: undefined reference to `CORE::BigFloatRep::operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
CMakeFiles/skeleton_generation.dir/skeleton_generation.cpp.o: In function `boost::optional<CGAL::Line_2<CGAL::Epeck> > CGAL::CGAL_SS_i::compute_normalized_line_ceoffC2<CGAL::Epeck>(CGAL::Segment_2<CGAL::Epeck> const&)':
/usr/include/CGAL/CORE/BigInt.h:126: undefined reference to `CORE::BigIntRep::operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
CMakeFiles/skeleton_generation.dir/skeleton_generation.cpp.o: In function `boost::optional<CGAL::Line_2<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<__gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]> > > > CGAL::CGAL_SS_i::compute_normalized_line_ceoffC2<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<__gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]> > >(CGAL::Segment_2<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<__gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]> > > const&)':
/usr/include/CGAL/CORE/BigFloat.h:64: undefined reference to `CORE::BigFloatRep::operator new(unsigned long)'
/usr/include/CGAL/CORE/BigFloat.h:64: undefined reference to `CORE::BigFloatRep::BigFloatRep(double)'
/usr/include/CGAL/CORE/BigFloat.h:54: undefined reference to `CORE::BigFloatRep::operator new(unsigned long)'
CMakeFiles/skeleton_generation.dir/skeleton_generation.cpp.o: In function `boost::optional<CGAL::Line_2<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<__gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]> > > > CGAL::CGAL_SS_i::compute_normalized_line_ceoffC2<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<__gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]> > >(CGAL::Segment_2<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<__gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]> > > const&)':
/usr/include/CGAL/CORE/BigInt.h:126: undefined reference to `CORE::BigIntRep::operator new(unsigned long)'
CMakeFiles/skeleton_generation.dir/skeleton_generation.cpp.o: In function `boost::optional<CGAL::Line_2<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<__gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]> > > > CGAL::CGAL_SS_i::compute_normalized_line_ceoffC2<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<__gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]> > >(CGAL::Segment_2<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<__gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]> > > const&)':
/usr/include/CGAL/CORE/BigFloat.h:354: undefined reference to `CORE::defBFsqrtAbsPrec'
/usr/include/CGAL/CORE/BigFloat.h:354: undefined reference to `CORE::BigFloatRep::sqrt(CORE::BigFloatRep const&, CORE::extLong const&)'
/usr/include/CGAL/CORE/BigFloat.h:221: undefined reference to `CORE::BigFloatRep::toDouble() const'
CMakeFiles/skeleton_generation.dir/skeleton_generation.cpp.o: In function `boost::optional<CGAL::Line_2<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<__gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]> > > > CGAL::CGAL_SS_i::compute_normalized_line_ceoffC2<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<__gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]> > >(CGAL::Segment_2<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<__gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]> > > const&)':
/usr/include/CGAL/CORE/RefCount.h:74: undefined reference to `CORE::BigIntRep::operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
/usr/include/CGAL/CORE/RefCount.h:74: undefined reference to `CORE::BigFloatRep::operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
/usr/include/CGAL/CORE/RefCount.h:74: undefined reference to `CORE::BigIntRep::operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
/usr/include/CGAL/CORE/RefCount.h:74: undefined reference to `CORE::BigFloatRep::operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
CMakeFiles/skeleton_generation.dir/skeleton_generation.cpp.o: In function `boost::optional<CGAL::Line_2<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<__gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]> > > > CGAL::CGAL_SS_i::compute_normalized_line_ceoffC2<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<__gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]> > >(CGAL::Segment_2<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<__gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]> > > const&)':
/usr/include/CGAL/CORE/BigFloat.h:64: undefined reference to `CORE::BigFloatRep::operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
/usr/include/CGAL/CORE/BigFloat.h:54: undefined reference to `CORE::BigFloatRep::operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
CMakeFiles/skeleton_generation.dir/skeleton_generation.cpp.o: In function `boost::optional<CGAL::Line_2<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<__gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]> > > > CGAL::CGAL_SS_i::compute_normalized_line_ceoffC2<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<__gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]> > >(CGAL::Segment_2<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<__gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]> > > const&)':
/usr/include/CGAL/CORE/BigInt.h:126: undefined reference to `CORE::BigIntRep::operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/skeleton_generation.dir/build.make:99: recipe for target 'skeleton_generation' failed
make[2]: *** [skeleton_generation] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/skeleton_generation.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/skeleton_generation.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Now, I *think* that I already have the dependencies met. So why would it still have these errors pop up? Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: `"print.h"`: using `""` instead of `<>` is a big hint that the file is expected to be in the same directory. So if you moved one and not the other...

Comment: cgal_create_CMakeLists takes options. You can use `-c ...` to tell it you are using Core, `-b ...` for boost_thread, etc. Run it once with -h to see the list of options. There may also be hints in the file CMakeLists.txt in the directory where you took the example.

Comment: @MarcGlisse You are right. I'm just a spoiled Python guy.

Comment: There are some python bindings for parts of cgal, if you want.